# Hibernate Transaction in iteration occurs errors

Tags: hibernate, transactions

I'm new to hibernate.
I want to use transaction in iterator, so i did like this (without business logic):

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
for {
    try {
        Something something = session.get(Something.class, id);
        something.setX(X);
        session.save(something)
        tx.commit(); <-- error occurs after iterated once.
    catch { tx.rollback(); }
}
Something something2 = session.get(Something.class, id2);
something2.setX(X);
session.save(something2);
tx.commit():
session.close();
```

But the hibernate occurs Transaction not successfully started error

So i changed code like this.

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx;
for {
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Something something = session.get(Something.class, id);
        something.setX(X);
        session.save(something)
        tx.commit();
    catch { tx.rollback(); }
}
session.beginTransaction();
Something something2 = session.get(Something.class, id2);
something2.setX(X);
session.save(something2);
tx.commit():
session.close();
```

This code works at the first time. But when i relaunch this program, it occurs `lock wait timeout exceeded`.
Although I have set innodb_lock_wait_timeout as 120 the result is same.
What wrong with that !?

Comment: Why you open session and transaction directly in code? Why you don't use annotations?

Comment: In second version, after the loop : `tx = session.beginTransaction();` . Can you post the trace for `lock wait timeout exceed` ?

Comment: Use finally {session.close();} after catch, Also the second transaction is not in try catch. I'm not quite sure about the syntax of -->for {